# Parts of my display are turning black on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, x11, display

As illustrated below, I occasionally encounter (but cannot recreate) display issues with mupdf on Linux Mint 17.2, whereby parts of the display turn black

[image]
[image]

and whereby all or parts of text being garbled

[image]

(The above shows garbling of black text and blue text.)

I have also observer some other issues that I forget.

What is going wrong?

**UPDATE** (18 Aug 2017). This issue persists in `mupdf-x11` v1.11, but not in `mupdf-gl` v1.11, so I presume there's a problem with X or mupdf's interaction with X.

Comment: What graphics card and drivers are you using? Random display glitches tend to be due to one of both of these.

Comment: Executing `lspci` produces _Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics_. Executing `lshw -c video` produces _configuration: driver=i915_.

Comment: it's really difficult to answer because this can be an issue related to some specific PDF file. second, I don't understand the last part of your question: > parts of the display appearing the wrong place, and some other issues that I forget is this mupdf related? or is another issue, living outside mupdf?

Comment: 1) The problem is not related to a specific PDF file, it occurs regularly with many PDFs (usually ones generated by pdflatex).
2) As an example of "parts of the display appearing the wrong place," consider lines of text sometimes appearing in the wrong place.
3) I don't think it is a mupdf issue; I suspect it is an issue with the library used by mupdf to display graphics.

Comment: I've just experienced "parts of the display appearing the wrong place," so I have edited my post to include a further screenshot that shows garbed text.

Answer (score 0):

Quite probably your problem is the PDF software or the production of your LaTeX file. I would check the possibilities in the following order:

1. Update: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. Try using another PDF reader:
   http://www.tecmint.com/linux-pdf-viewers-and-readers-tools/
3. (Re)install the full LaTeX suite `apt-get install texlive`
4. Check the Mint Driver Management in your computer and change the driver for your graphic chipset. Look for it in the Application menu, else install it: 

   `sudo apt-get install mintdrivers`

   Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/linux-mint-driver-manager-and-device.html
5. Install another Window manager. Mate and XFCE are my favourites because they are light weight

I have 17.1 LTE XFCE and i don't have this problem.

Comment: I'm up to date (1). Switching PDF readers isn't an option (2). This isn't a LaTeX problem (3). I'm willing to change drivers (4); can you suggest a specific way to do this, rather than a generic, third party tool? Switching windows managers isn't an option (5).

I should stress that mupdf works perfectly on other devices running Linux Mint.